# Samsung TV emulator does not work from eclipse

Tags: eclipse, emulation, samsung-smart-tv

Hey guys i want to run a simple hello world application on Samsung smart TV emulator but when i run my project as Samsung smart TV application .. an exception appeared which is :

```
Could not find a registration machine please check emulator sittings from Samsung smart TV preference page
```

I installed the SDK 5, the virtual box, and import the SDK emulator image
I also follow [this](http://www.samsungdforum.com/SamsungDForum/ForumView/7e2b7fa90012098b?forumID=6e850ef152a4495f) solution But also its not working.

Can anybody knows How to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem is in your virtual box. Have you downloaded the official one from Oracle. This version is working for me with SDK for Eclipse 4.5:

[Virtual Box](http://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/4.3.2/)

**Edit after comments:**

Emulator settings in Eclipse Samsung SDK 4.5 Linux

[image: Emulator settings in Eclipse Samsung SDK 4.5 Linux]

Comment: i downloaded this version but the emulator dose not working from the eclipse, rather than when i run the emulator from virtual box its working!! whats the problem!! thanx for replaying

Comment: What do you mean by installing the sdk emulator image?
Did you install the SDK or just the emulator image?
What happens if you run the emulator from eclipse?
What if you run it just from the virtual machine?

Comment: yeah i installed SDK and the the emulator image, when i run the emulator from eclipse its give me this exception : Could not find a registration machine please check emulator sittings from Samsung smart TV preference page..... but its working from the virtual box!!

Comment: So why not use just that? 
By the way this is my settings page in Eclipse running from a Linux box.
[Emulator Settings](http://s21.postimg.org/k9dujok5z/emulatorsettings.png)

Comment: ohhh, thanx @andrea-f i tried to install the old version from Samsung SDK 4.5 ...and it works!! i don't know whats wrong with the latest version Samsung SDK 5.0!!! its sucks!!  Thanx a lot for your help,, really i appreciate that :)

Comment: I had the same problem, i installed the old version from emulator (2013 Smart_TV_Emulater_4_5)...and it worked very well